# Bash quoting problem

Tags: bash

```
A="echo 'q'"

$A
```

I got the result 'q'

but if I type echo 'q' directly, it's q (without single quote)

So, I wonder what rule does bash follow while facing single quotes inside the double quotes.

The original problem is

```
A="curl http://123.196.125.62/send -H 'Host: poj.org' -e http://poj.org/send"

$A
```

I got curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'poj.org''

it will be all right if I just type the command into the terminal..

P.S. I'd like to use $A for excuting the command inside A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to "save" a command for later execution, you do **NOT** want a variable.  You want a function.

```
a() { curl http://123.196.125.62/send -H 'Host: poj.org' -e http://poj.org/send; }
```

Putting code in variables is **bad** since variables are containers for *data* not *code*.  Additionally, you are seeing the problem because `$A` does **NOT** execute the bash code in `A`, what it really does is split the value of `A` into words, then it performs *Pathname Expansion* on these words, and as a result of those two operations, it executes a program named by the first resulting word and passes the other words as arguments.  In your particular case, this is what happens (I use `[]` to indicate "units"):

```
A:                        [echo 'q']
after wordsplitting:      [echo] ['q']
after pathname expansion: [echo] ['q']
```

Now bash looks for a program called `echo` and passes the argument `'q'` to it.

This is NOT executing bash code, because if you execute `echo 'q'` as bash code, bash removes the single quotes after it's done with them.  Similarly, you cannot do pipes, redirection et al. like this, because they too are bash syntax (just like your single quotes).

Recap: *never* put code in bash variables.  *never* leave parameters unquoted (if you think doing that fixes something, you are wrong, you've just made things worse, go fix the real problem).  The solution is to use a `function`.

Comment: it seems to be odd that the translation of single quotes won't be done after the Pathname Expansion... Thanks anyway

Comment: Not at all, data is not parsed as though it were bash syntax.  If it were, that would be all too crazy.

Answer (score 6):

Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!

It's best to avoid putting commands in variables for the reason you've experienced, among others.

You should use a function and pass it arguments.

Why do you want to do this rather than simply executing the command directly?

If you must do it, use an array:

```
A=(curl http://123.196.125.62/send -H 'Host: poj.org' -e http://poj.org/send)
${A[@]}
```

Regarding the treatment of single quotes within double quotes, they are treated literally and as part of the rest of the string. Here is the relevant paragraph from `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the  literal  value  of
>          all  characters  within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,
>          when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $  and  `  retain
>          their  special meaning within double quotes.  The backslash retains its
>          special meaning only when followed by one of the following  characters:
>          $,  `,  ", \, or `<newline>`.  A double quote may be quoted within double
>          quotes by preceding it with a backslash.  If enabled, history expansion
>          will  be  performed  unless an !  appearing in double quotes is escaped
>          using a backslash.  The backslash preceding the !  is not removed.

Comment: Should that be `${A[@]}` instead? Definitely a better approach than `eval`! +1

Comment: good answer and really great alternation! However, I prefer lhunath's explanation..sorry.. but your work is appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use backquotes in this case:

```
A=`curl http://123.196.125.62/send -H 'Host: poj.org' -e 'http://poj.org/send'`
```

Comment: sorry, I did't mention that I'd like to use $A for excuting the command inside A